# Add url field on SonataMediaBundle Image provider

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I'm using Symfony 2.3 and an implementation of SonataMediaBundle with SonataAdminBundle.

I would like to know how could I add an extra field **"URL"** on the creation form and allow users to upload its owns files from their computer or passing an URL from some picture on the web. Then I will get the image and store it as a media record.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install the **Sonata Media Bundle**:
[Media's documentation - Index  (master)](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/index.html)

Run the Sonata Extends for the Media Bundle.
You can then add any kind of file to your entities e.g.:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade="all")
 */
private $invoice;
```